# Are there any tool to parse a C file and show my code layout in a treeview, so I can easily tell which #defines a function depends on to be compiled?

Tags: c, preprocessor

The question is pretty straight forward. I'm currently using Source Insight, but its parsing of preprocessor macros is not perfect. I need a reliable tool to show me the treeview of nested `#ifdef` and `#if` macros.

I'm writing a new function, and I need to know in which "scope" to put it, to avoid cluttering the global namespace when the `#define`s this function depends on aren't defined.

Comment: Notepad++ can allow you to collapse source based on #ifdef levels

Comment: And it has been on my desktop for ages, but not for C development. Thank you. Please, make this an answer so I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: Hi, for future reference you should mention what environment (OS) you're using when asking for tools recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any editor or IDE that supports code folding should allow you to collapse and expand blocks of code.  I personally like using [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/cdt/), as it will go a step farther and automatically determine which `#ifdef` blocks are inactive.  Inactive code is grayed out and automatically collapsed.  Eclipse will also mark certain types of errors, such as undefined identifiers.  This should also help in your case because if you write a function in the wrong "scope" and it uses a function that is currently not available due to `#ifdef`, the IDE will mark the function call as a "call to an undefined function".

Comment: Probably overkill at this point in time. The project is more than 10 years old, I wouldn't be able to port it to Eclipse without much effort. Each platform have it's set of #defines, and the build script may set or unset additional flags. I won't accept this just because I've used notepad++ as a quick hack to the kernel of the problem.

Comment: @Spidey- Eclipse is an IDE.  You don't 'port' code to Eclipse, you simply open it as you would in any IDE/editor.  Eclipse has a dialog that lets you specify any macros that your build script defines on the command-line, and it will use those in its analysis as well (we do this all the time).

Comment: I meant porting the build scripts. I'm using nmake to build the project, but each platform has it's own include file with rules, targets and variables. It's a mess.
I've worked with Eclipse with J2EE and Android development, but I felt that the error detection engine depended on the output of the compiler. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Spidey- No. Eclipse/CDT uses its own parser engine called DOM (Document Object Model) parsers. see this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/Overview_of_Parsing. You just need to import your project into Eclipse as a ordinary C project and doesn't need to do anything more. It will parse your code fast and show various code information including tree view. (Note that you may want to add separate include file directories in <Project Properties> --> <C/C++ General> --> <Path and Symbos> --> <Include> --> <GNU C>

Comment: @Spidey- Eclipse can integrate with your build system, but it's not a requirement by any means.  I use Eclipse, and all of my projects use hand-written makefiles/scripts for building.  Other than editing them in the Eclipse editor, Eclipse doesn't have anything to do with my build scripts.

Comment: In this case, I'm accepting this answer. Thank you both (bta and Jason Geng) for the references.